# Unable to call for a module in a different folder

Tags: python, directory, python-import

I cloned [a repository of a Facebook research project](https://github.com/facebookresearch/DrQA) tried run `python scripts/pipeline/interactive.py` to launch a program as told in the README. Yet it I always have the following issue `ModuleNotFoundError`. Indeed the file I call with `python` call for another one which isn't in the same directory.

Here is the full error :

```
.
├── drqa
│   ├── pipeline
│   │   └── __pycache__
│   ...
...
├── scripts
│   ├── convert
│   ├── distant
│   ├── pipeline
│   ├── reader
│   └── retriever
```

And here is the `interactive.py` script:

```
from termcolor import colored
from drqa import pipeline
from drqa.retriever import utils
```

I am worried because this work might be a great one as far as it was made by Facebook research team. I must have missed something.

It may be related to the fact that I didn't perfectly understood this part of the README:

> Note: requirements.txt includes a subset of all the possible required
>   packages. Depending on what you want to run, you might need to install
>   an extra package (e.g. spacy).
>
> If you use the CoreNLPTokenizer or SpacyTokenizer you also need to
>   download the Stanford CoreNLP jars and spaCy en model, respectively.
>   If you use Stanford CoreNLP, have the jars in your java CLASSPATH
>   environment variable, or set the path programmatically with:
>
> ```
> import drqa.tokenizers drqa.tokenizers.set_default('corenlp_classpath', '/your/corenlp/classpath/*')
> ```
>
> IMPORTANT: The default tokenizer is CoreNLP so you will need that in
>   your CLASSPATH to run the README examples.
>
> Ex: `export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/path/to/corenlp/download/*`.
>
> If you do not already have a CoreNLP download you can run:
>
> `./install_corenlp.sh`
>
> Verify that it runs:
>
> ```
> from drqa.tokenizers import CoreNLPTokenizer tok = CoreNLPTokenizer() tok.tokenize('hello world').words()  # Should complete immediately
> ```
>
> For convenience, the Document Reader, Retriever, and Pipeline modules
>   will try to load default models if no model argument is given. See
>   below for downloading these models.

If I did installed `./install_corenlp.sh` I wasn't able to export the classpath because I wasn't able to know what `/path/to/corenlp/download/*` was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your scripts with python from the root directory '.' and add to your environment :

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=".":$PYTHONPATH
```

So that python can know '.' is a `source root`